# Fetching the value of a child tag in XML when the Xpath is repeating using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

I have an XPath lets say "/rrr/aaa/Parenttag/Childtag" under a parent . I need to fetch the value present in the Child tag. This Xpath is repeating multiple times in the same Xml document. So I'm using "*/rrr/aaa/Parenttag/Childtag" with the '*' (asterisk) in the beginning.

The issue I'm facing now is that my Xpath is also a part another parent . As I'm using the "*", the data from  is also being fetched. Is there a way to get the data only from  and not any other Parents?

I hope my explanation was understandable.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

I'm unable to upload the actual XML. So here is a snippet of the structure of XML that I have.

[Please click link to see an image of how my data is structured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l5tM.png)

The XPath is /rrr/aaa/bbb. I need the values present in bbb for all the times it is repeating. Im using */rrr/aaa/bbb to as the Xpath using the following code to the data that I want. However, I need the data that is present only under the parent tag . The same tags are repeated under .

```
Range("A2").Value = "*/rrr/aaa/bbb"

Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(Range("A2").Value)

For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1

    For Each chlnodes In nodeXML(i).ParentNode.ChildNodes
           Next chlnodes

    Range("B" & i + 1).Value = nodeXML(i).Text
Next
```

Hope this makes more sense.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(Range("A2").Value)
For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
     
    For Each chlnodes In nodeXML(i).ParentNode.ChildNodes
                    
    Next chlnodes

    Range("B" & i + 1).Value = nodeXML(i).Text
Next I have something likr this

Comment: Can you share XML sample for the same along with the current and desired output

Comment: Andersson, I have made an edit in my question. Can you see if it helps.I need the data under that tag <bbb>, but only for the parent tag <root1> not <root2>

Comment: So why you cannot use `root1/rrr/aaa/bbb`?

Comment: If I do that I will only get the first value. I wont get Value2 and Value3

Comment: No. This XPath should fetch all 3 values

Comment: Andersson, Thanks A ton.. That actually works.. I was using an asterisk in front of the Xpath and it ws not working.. Whatever you have suggested works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Andersson

```
root1/rrr/aaa/bbb
```

Comment: @andersson - if you wish to potentially earn rep from this please post as answer and leave a comment here and this will be deleted.